# PInescript - Memory limit exceeded by 1.2 times

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I know that pinescript allows only 40 request.security() functions(only 30 were used here). but when I write the code as shown below, it throws 'Memory exceeded' error. Can anyone help to know why this is happening and if there is any better way to write it.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Error - Instruments", overlay = true)
// ROC_N
func_rocn() =>
    r1=ta.roc(close, 10)
    r2=ta.roc(close, 20)
    [r1, r2]

[n10, n20] = request.security('NIFTY', '', func_rocn())

// ROC
func_roc() =>
    res = (ta.roc(close, 10) - n10) + (ta.roc(close, 20) - n20)
    math.round(res,1)

fc_roca2 = request.security('ADANIENT', '', func_roc())
fc_roca3 = request.security('ADANIPORTS', '', func_roc())
fc_roca4 = request.security('APOLLOHOSP', '', func_roc())
fc_roca5 = request.security('ASIANPAINT', '', func_roc())
fc_roca6 = request.security('AXISBANK', '', func_roc())
fc_roca7 = request.security('BAJAJ_AUTO', '', func_roc())
fc_roca8 = request.security('BAJFINANCE', '', func_roc())
fc_roca9 = request.security('BAJAJFINSV', '', func_roc())
fc_roca10 = request.security('BHARTIARTL', '', func_roc())
fc_roca11 = request.security('BRITANNIA', '', func_roc())
fc_roca12 = request.security('CIPLA', '', func_roc())
fc_roca13 = request.security('COALINDIA', '', func_roc())
fc_roca14 = request.security('DIVISLAB', '', func_roc())
fc_roca15 = request.security('DRREDDY', '', func_roc())
fc_roca16 = request.security('EICHERMOT', '', func_roc())
fc_roca17 = request.security('GRASIM', '', func_roc())
fc_roca18 = request.security('HCLTECH', '', func_roc())
fc_roca19 = request.security('HDFCBANK', '', func_roc())
fc_roca20 = request.security('HDFCLIFE', '', func_roc())
fc_roca21 = request.security('HEROMOTOCO', '', func_roc())
fc_roca22 = request.security('HINDALCO', '', func_roc())
fc_roca23 = request.security('HINDUNILVR', '', func_roc())
fc_roca24 = request.security('ICICIBANK', '', func_roc())
fc_roca25 = request.security('ITC', '', func_roc())
fc_roca26 = request.security('INDUSINDBK', '', func_roc())
fc_roca27 = request.security('INFY', '', func_roc())
fc_roca28 = request.security('JSWSTEEL', '', func_roc())
fc_roca29 = request.security('KOTAKBANK', '', func_roc())
fc_roca30 = request.security('LTIM', '', func_roc())


var tb1 = table.new(position.top_right, 5, 40, color.white, color.aqua, 1, color.aqua, 1)

if barstate.islast
    table.cell(tb1, 0, 1, str.tostring(fc_roca2))
    table.cell(tb1, 0, 2, str.tostring(fc_roca3))
    table.cell(tb1, 0, 3, str.tostring(fc_roca4))
    table.cell(tb1, 0, 4, str.tostring(fc_roca5))
    table.cell(tb1, 0, 5, str.tostring(fc_roca6))
    table.cell(tb1, 0, 6, str.tostring(fc_roca7))
    table.cell(tb1, 0, 7, str.tostring(fc_roca8))
    table.cell(tb1, 0, 8, str.tostring(fc_roca9))
    table.cell(tb1, 0, 9, str.tostring(fc_roca10))
    table.cell(tb1, 0, 10, str.tostring(fc_roca11))
    table.cell(tb1, 1, 1, str.tostring(fc_roca12))
    table.cell(tb1, 1, 2, str.tostring(fc_roca13))
    table.cell(tb1, 1, 3, str.tostring(fc_roca14))
    table.cell(tb1, 1, 4, str.tostring(fc_roca15))
    table.cell(tb1, 1, 5, str.tostring(fc_roca16))
    table.cell(tb1, 1, 6, str.tostring(fc_roca17))
    table.cell(tb1, 1, 7, str.tostring(fc_roca18))
    table.cell(tb1, 1, 8, str.tostring(fc_roca19))
    table.cell(tb1, 1, 9, str.tostring(fc_roca20))
    table.cell(tb1, 1, 10, str.tostring(fc_roca21))
    table.cell(tb1, 2, 1, str.tostring(fc_roca22))
    table.cell(tb1, 2, 2, str.tostring(fc_roca23))
    table.cell(tb1, 2, 3, str.tostring(fc_roca24))
    table.cell(tb1, 2, 4, str.tostring(fc_roca25))
    table.cell(tb1, 2, 5, str.tostring(fc_roca26))
    table.cell(tb1, 2, 6, str.tostring(fc_roca27))
    table.cell(tb1, 2, 7, str.tostring(fc_roca28))
    table.cell(tb1, 2, 8, str.tostring(fc_roca29))
    table.cell(tb1, 2, 9, str.tostring(fc_roca30))
```

It loads without any issue, but when I try to play in replay mode on any instruments, especially on lower timeframes it throws an error. "Memory Limits exceeded. Study allocates 1.2 times more than allowed"

My main checks were done on NIFTY/5M.

Comment: Is this your whole code? There doesn't seem any issues with this code. It is just `request.security()` is a very expensive function. Even though the limit is 40, it doesn't mean you will have no issues with 30 calls.

Comment: I think this isn't full code, you didn't use any of these fc_roca's, above mentioned code is ok, you should give more info to get support.

Comment: @vitruvius, thanks for the input. but do you think there any better way to write the func_rocn() and func_roc() to decrease the load on the memory.

Comment: @ArmanAzadi - You may pls check it now, I have updated the code and given more info at the bottom of the script, so you can replicate the error on your end and help me with the issue.